# Retrieving OptimisationScore

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, adsense, google-ads-script

Recently I have been trying to create a script to retrieve either an accounts or individual campaigns optimisation scores and subsequently send a email including this. My problem is that I cannot find optimisation score in stats or metrics anyway I try.

Does anyone know if this is even a retrievable variable in scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate this yourself.
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/recommendations

The Customer.optimization_score_weight is only available for non-manager accounts and is used to compute the overall optimization score of multiple accounts. Retrieve the optimization score and optimization score weight of the accounts and multiply them together (Customer.optimization_score * Customer.optimization_score_weight) to compute the overall optimization score.